# WixUI_Advanced fails ACK for per-user test

Tags: wix, windows-installer, app-certification-kit

I am creating an desktop app MSI that using `WixUI_Advanced` for dual scope support. However the production MSI causes a warning on Windows App Certification Kit:

```
WARNING    Install to Program Files
           * Warning: The install to Program Files test detected the following errors:
             * Program xxxx fails due to install location C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Apps\XXX
```

I was confused. The ACK being used is the Version 2.2, and the warning message shows the CORRECT behavior of a per-user installer (since install to `Program Files` requires privilege). But why it shows the warning? Are there any body have the same problem?

**UPDATE**

It seems like a bug of `WixUI_Advanced`. According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd770204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the redirected folder name for per-user install is `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\XXX` rather than `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Apps\XXX`.

Answer (score 1):

Even you set the install location to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\XXX` the same warning still shows, the same thing happens for ACK version 3.0 (for Windows 8.1) as well.

Furthermore, when doing an x64 per-user test it also warns for the uninstall registry keys. There is no way to set those keys in other ways.

Microsoft confirmed this warning is ignorable and will not affect the certification result, but they did not say anything about weather it is a bug or not, not saying any plan to fix either.